# Gradle - unable to echo a huge string to a temp file (.js)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gradle, escaping

I have a gradle task that takes a string and saves it to a .js file.

it looks like this:

```
task myTask() << {
....
executeSudo('echo "' + script + '" > tempFile.js')
```

My script file is a mongoDB script (.js type).
I am facing errors while calling the "echo" command due to probably illegal characters in the .js file.

How can i prevent such errors from occuring? i takes me a long time to figure out where the error occurs on the .js file. isnt there a way to escape all illegal chars on that strings before echoing?

here is a part from my .js file:

```
if (currentVersion == 26) {
// ***********************************************************************
// ****************************** START VERSION 26 ************************
// ***********************************************************************


db.Application.insert({
    name : 'crp',
    operatorId : 1,
    metaData : {
        label : 'VIP',
        title : 'tabs.title',
        icon : 'fa fa-support',
        color : 'btn-success'
    },
    widgets : [ {
        name : 'dashboard',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Dashboard',
            label : 'Dashboard',
            icon : 'fa fa-line-chart'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'vip-requests',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Requests',
            label : 'Requests',
            icon : 'fa fa-circle-o-notch'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'declined',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Declined',
            label : 'Declined',
            icon : 'fa fa-thumbs-down'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'approved',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Approved',
            label : 'Approved',
            icon : 'fa fa-money'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'manage-ers',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Manage ers',
            label : 'Manage ers',
            icon : 'fa fa-briefcase'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'manage-campaigns',
        metaData : {
            title : 'Manage Campaigns',
            label : 'Manage Campaigns',
            icon : 'fa fa-magic'
        }
    }, {
        name : 'something-assignment-rules',
        metaData : {
            title : 'ttt',
            label : 'aaa',
            icon : 'fa fa-magnet'
        }
    } ]
});

currentVersion = currentVersion + 1

// ***********************************************************************
// ****************************** END VERSION 26 **************************
// ***********************************************************************
```

}

EDIT #2:

```
  task refreshDBWithParameters() << {
  ....
  println "Starting build task"
  String script = new File(mongoScriptPath).getText('UTF-8')

  sshexec{
  session(remotes.mongoDbServer) {

    println "Updating Mongo DB...";
    //THE FOLLOWING LINE IS FAILING:
    executeSudo('echo "' + script + '" > tempFile.js')
    executeSudo("mongo " + mongoDataBaseName  + " tempFile.js")
    executeSudo("rm tempFile.js")
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole script?

Comment: `js` script itself isn't as interesting as `executeSudo` method. What I meant when writing *script* was rather **build.gradle**.

Comment: What were the errors in JS file? How is this file generated?